# VMWare Player - Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS fails to login

Tags: 14.04, vmware

I have *VMWare Player 7* installed on my Windows 10 machine. I have *Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS* installed on it. I installed it a few weeks ago before school to get things ready on it. Everything worked fine until today. Each time I log in and accepts my password. I have a terminal automatically start up on boot, and once that shows up it logs me out. It does this for my local account and the guest account. I haven't changed anything in the VM. The settings are default, I allocate 2 GB of RAM to it, and 2 processor cores.

I took the `.iso` file from my desktop and tried reinstalling the VM on my laptop again but the same thing happens. The install goes perfectly fine, it creates the split disk files, etc. I have no idea what is going on. Any suggestions would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem. After looking through many forums and other questions on SuperUser, I was able to locate the problem.

A user [here](https://superuser.com/questions/791415/used-vmware-player-free-and-now-cant-login-to-ubuntu-after-reboot) stated that they were messing around with video drivers, which caused the `AMQP service` to fail.

My laptop (Lenovo p500) has a bug to where dimming the brightness sometimes turns off the screen backlight, and it happened to me earlier today. The only way to get it to return is to roll back the driver. It reset it back to the `Windows Basic Display Driver`. After searching for a driver update and reinstalling the `Intel HD 4000` graphics drivers, I was able to log into Ubuntu again.